# Timeout when starting xcuitrunner

Tags: windows, ios

We're using xcuitrunner on Windows to start the Facebook WebDriverAgent on iOS devices.

We're getting a timeout error when using xcuitrunner:

```
Machine ID: XXXXXX
Using a license for [X] which expires on 1/1/2010 5:30:00 AM

The Xcode UI Test will be resigned:
- Developer Certificate: [X]
- Provisioning Profile: [X]

Starting the Xcode UI Test

Unhandled Exception: System.TimeoutException: The test plan did not start on the mobile device within the alloted timeframe of 120 s.
  at XcuitRunner.WebDriverAgentInstaller.LaunchXcuiTest(String udid, String testBundleIdentifier, String moduleName, AppleVersion xctestVersion, Version iosVersion, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  at XcuitRunner.WebDriverAgentInstaller.LaunchXcuiTest(String udid, String testBundlePath, CodeSignSettings settings, Dictionary`2 customEnvironment, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  at XcuitRunner.XcuitRunner.Run(ProgramOptions options)
  at XcuitRunner.Program.<>c__DisplayClass5_1.<Main>b__2()
  at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
  at XcuitRunner.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

We are getting this on multiple machines. We restarted the device as well and checked but we are still getting the issue.

How can we resolve this?

Comment: Can you check whether you've enabled UI automation on the device? You can do so by going to *Settings* - *Developer* - *Enable UI Automation*. This option should be enabled. If not, please enable that option & try again.

Comment: Yes, that option is enabled. Anything else I can try?

Comment: Thanks. This is probably because the WebDriverAgent app itself fails to launch on your iOS device. This is usually because one or more of your developer certificates have expired or been revoked. Have you recently revoked one of your developer certificates?

Comment: No they have not been revoked. I previously used the same profile and xcuitrunner started just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the logs you've sent me, it does seem this is a code signing issue. It looks like one of the certificates in your developer profile have been revoked (perhaps recently). This would explain why the WebDriverAgent fails to launch on your iOS device, and why you get the timeout (xcuitrunner will attempt to connect to the WebDriverAgent which never launches):

```
May 16 14:16:13 iPhone amfid[390] <Notice>: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6FEACA16-ED28-4D85-96BB-595BB7F32F0B/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner not valid: 0xe8008018: The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid.
May 16 14:16:13 iPhone kernel(AppleMobileFileIntegrity)[0] <Notice>: AMFI: code signature validation failed.
```

To fix this:

1. Remove all revoked certificates from your developer profile. Ideally, just keep on certificate which you know is good in your developer profile.
2. Remove the *WebDriverAgent* app from the device
3. Delete all `.ipa` files in the xcuitrunner folder
4. Restart xcuitrunner

If this still fails, please capture the `idevicesyslog` output once more and send it to me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you capture additional information and send that to me? You can contact me at [first name].[last name]@quamotion.mobi .

1. Open a command prompt, and navigate to the folder where xcuitrunner is located
2. Type `ideviceinfo.exe > deviceinfo.txt`
3. Type `idevicesyslog.exe > syslog.txt`
   The application will remain running until you stop it by typing CTRL+C. Don’t stop it yet.
4. Open a second command prompt, and navigate to the folder where xcuitrunner is located
5. Launch xcuitrunner, and wait for the error to occur
6. In the first command prompt window, type CTRL+C to stop idevicesyslog
7. Send me a copy of `deviceinfo.txt` and `syslog.txt`